# A question on handles in embedded C

Tags: c, embedded, pointers

Regarding handle concept in C the following is stated:

> The term handle is sometimes confused with a pointer. A handle is a
> reference to a system resource. Access to the resource is provided
> through the handle. However, the handle generally does not provide
> direct access to the resource. In contrast, a pointer contains the
> resource’s address.

As an example inside a header file there is:

```
/*! Device Handle */
typedef void * DEV_HANDLE;

/*! Buffer Handle */
typedef void * BUFFER_HANDLE;
```

And for instance it is used in a DLL as:

```
int CDECL functionName(DEV_HANDLE hDevice, BUFFER_HANDLE hBuffer );
```

What is the purpose of these handles? Why not just pointers used instead?

Comment: This site is for questions on **electronic design** so circuits etc.

Comment: But the examples you give _are_ just pointers.

Comment: A "handle" is a thing through which you can access a certain object. It can be number (an index in some array), it can be a string (some unique identifier), it can be a pointer (that is pointing to that object. There is no "handle" as a separate concept in C.

Comment: Being declared as a pointer does not mean it actually points. For example, on WIN32 a `HANDLE` could be a small well-known constant, a pointer in a different memory space, etc, but it's *declared* `typedef PVOID HANDLE;`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/902969/1424875 is a good resource to read.

Comment: GNZ - Hi, While questions around writing firmware are [on-topic](/help/on-topic) here, this looks *much* more of a software-only question (i.e. there is no mention of hardware) so I recommend you consider asking it on Stack Overflow instead (after searching for existing answers).

Comment: Handles are a bit like a train ticket. You pay your money and receive a ticket. The ticket isnt the train ride - it allows you access to a train ride. One example of handles is filesystem access. You call the open function and it returns an error or a handle. The handle is essential a number - the first file you open might be a value of 1. Why use a handle? The filesystem code can hide its data rather than exposing it via a pointer.

Comment: The difference is that a handle is [**opaque**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type). This is a critical concept. It means _you neither care nor even know_ "what" the thing is. It doesn't matter to you. Only the implementation knows and cares. It allows for implementation hiding (separation of interface and implementation). These are your search terms to learn more (opaque, implementation hiding).

Comment: @TypeIA being opaque is not a necessary property of a handle. Handle is just a concept of something "small" to represent something "big".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)

Comment: What is the difference between: Handle, Pointer and Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023405/what-is-the-difference-between-handle-pointer-and-reference

Comment: Handles aren't native to C language; the critical missing concept is a memory management concept called "garbage collection" which sweeps up unused deleted objects. Languages like Java, Python, C#, etc. use "garbage collection" to periodically shuffle the physical location of objects in memory, to help consolidate free space to help avoid out-of-memory errors. Plain C pointers can't be updated by the memory management system. Handles are indirect, reference-counting pointers that the memory management system uses to track which objects are still in use and where they are in memory.

Comment: I can mention that hiding pointers behind `typedef` is widely recognized as very bad practice, _even_ for the purposes of opaque pointers. The Windows API type system has received massive criticism over the years and using "handles" to hide pointers is one of the reasons for that. Here's an example of how to implement opaque type without hiding pointers: [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888)

Comment: For an embedded system's point-of-view, this might also be of interest: [Static allocation of opaque data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440476/static-allocation-of-opaque-data-types)

Answer (score 1):

Let's be honest, a handle usually is a pointer. It's probably a pointer to some data struct. Though as some commenters have said, it doesn't have to be. It could be an integer cast to a "void *", just to mislead you.

The thinking behind a "handle" is that it's opaque. Even if it really is a pointer, it's been cast to "void *", so you have no idea what it's a pointer to. That discourages you from fiddling with it. Instead, you receive it from some library call, keep it safe, then pass it back into another library call.